# kubernetes ingress websockets (socket.io)

Tags: flask, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, flask-socketio

I keep getting bad requests (400) when trying to open a websocket, and I'm trying to figure out why. The back-end is built on flask with flask-socketio. Here is my Docker container for the back-end:

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN apk update
RUN apk add python3 py3-cffi py3-bcrypt libc-dev py3-psycopg2 py3-gevent
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install flask flask-restful flask-jwt-extended gunicorn requests flask-sqlalchemy flask-socketio

ADD ./rest-api /root/rest-api
ADD ./ui/dist/ui /root/ui

CMD ["gunicorn", "-k", "gevent", "-w", "1", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:3001", "--access-logfile", "-", "--chdir", "/root/rest-api/", "app:app"]
```

Here are my yaml files:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-global-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: my-certificate
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: "my-service-web"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /grafana/*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service-web
          servicePort: grafana-port
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service-web
          servicePort: web-app-port
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service-web

spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      name: grafana-port
      targetPort: grafana-port
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 3001
      name: web-app-port
      targetPort: web-app-port
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-cloud
  type: NodePort
```

I can see from the logs that the requests reach the back-end container:

```
10.166.0.42 - - [26/Nov/2019:08:52:22 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
10.4.2.1 - - [26/Nov/2019:08:52:23 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
10.4.2.1 - - [26/Nov/2019:08:52:25 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
10.4.2.1 - - [26/Nov/2019:08:52:28 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
10.4.2.1 - - [26/Nov/2019:08:52:34 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
10.166.0.41 - - [26/Nov/2019:08:52:39 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
10.166.0.41 - - [26/Nov/2019:08:52:44 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
10.166.0.42 - - [26/Nov/2019:08:52:49 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
10.4.2.1 - - [26/Nov/2019:08:52:54 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
```

What I can't figure out is how to configure kubernetes ingress to follow flask-socketio configuration for nginx:

```
    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }
```

How do I do the connection upgrade to websocket in kubernetes ingress?

Update:
I instantiated SocketIO with logs enabled and got the following:

```
6f3a03945f174b039b033e887079b97d: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '6f3a03945f174b039b033e887079b97d', 'upgrades': [], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
6f3a03945f174b039b033e887079b97d: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
6f3a03945f174b039b033e887079b97d: Received request to upgrade to websocket
10.166.0.43 - - [26/Nov/2019:10:19:45 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
```

Comment: ingress-nginx is coming with websockets enabled by default https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#websockets, so I would look at application, rather then in k8s. Also you can try connecting to nodeport directly bypassing ingress-nginx.

Comment: How many web workers do you have? If you use more than one, then you need to use sticky sessions in your nginx configuration.

Comment: @Miguel Hi Miguel. I'm using 1 worker. The thing is that I don't know how to configure the kubernetes ingress nginx to upgrade the connection to websocket. If I change transport to 'polling' in my client app then everything works fine but that's not pure websockets (I can use polling for now). I have my own vm with nginx (properly configured) where websockets work just fine following the docs from flask-socketio. I'm working on moving that vm to a container on kubernetes.

Comment: Have you done [that](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/websocket)? Take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/jsdevtom/7045c03c021ce46b08cb3f41db0d76da#file-ingress-service-yaml) also.

Comment: @mWatney I just tried what they show in those links and it doesn't work. My websocket connection works only in polling mode (I'm using socket.io). But the upgrade to 101 fails. Have you got websockets up and running on kubernetes (flask-socketio backend)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost had it right from the beginning. I changed the `CMD` in my `Dockerfile` to (as per Flask-socketio docs):

`gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 module:app`

Here's the complete `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add python3 py3-cffi py3-bcrypt libc-dev py3-psycopg2 py3-gevent-websocket
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install flask flask-restful flask-jwt-extended gunicorn requests flask-sqlalchemy flask-socketio

ADD ./rest-api /root/rest-api
ADD ./ui/dist/ui /root/ui

CMD ["gunicorn", "-k", "geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker", "-w", "1", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:3001", "--timeout", "180", "--access-logfile", "-", "--chdir", "/root/rest-api/", "app:app"]
```

Comment: this should really be upvoted more. thank you!!